# Why are generic arguments described by `T@function_name` by pyright?

Tags: python, pyright

Given the following block of code:

```py
import typing as tp

T = tp.TypeVar("T")

def dummy(item: T) -> T:
    return item

reveal_type(dummy)
```

When run onto it, `pyright` prints:

```
❯ pyright type_arobase.py
< some output trimmed >
/home/gregoire.roussel/dev/wdc/python/type_arobase.py
  /home/gregoire.roussel/dev/wdc/python/type_arobase.py:8:13 - information: Type of "dummy" is "(item: T@dummy) -> T@dummy"
0 errors, 0 warnings, 1 information 
Completed in 0.617sec
```

Note the `T@dummy` in the output.

- Why does `pyright` feel the need to suffix all generic types with a `@function_name` ?
- What additional information does it bring compared to the original signature `(item: T) -> T` ?

Note: I found in the pyright doc [this paragraph](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/type-concepts.md#inferred-type-of-self-and-cls-parameters) that mentions this phenomenon in the special case of `self` and `cls` argument, without more details.